# Joomla 404 - Component not found after upgrading core files

Tags: joomla

After my Joomla got attacked, I was recommended to update my core Joomla files. I did that and I was finally able to login to the admin page. But I got the '404 - Component not found' in my index.php page.

```
Component not found.

Call stack
Function                        Location
1   JApplicationCms->execute()  \index.php:49
2   JApplicationSite->doExecute()   \libraries\cms\application\cms.php:257
3   JApplicationSite->dispatch()    \libraries\cms\application\site.php:230
4   JComponentHelper::renderComponent() \libraries\cms\application\site.php:191
```

Did anyone come across this issue and got it solved. I couldn't find it so my last hope is here.

Answer (score 1):

When you are manually updating Joomla you need to be careful as you have to follow certain steps after overwriting the files.

1) First you need to fix the database as the tables are now changed and overwriting files will not update database. For that you need to go to administrator and then you have to go to Extensions->manage->Database and then click on Fix Database. That will update your database too.

2) Next you have to install the extensions that came with new Joomla version. These are not yet updated in #__assets table. SO you go to Extensions->manage->Discover and then click on Discover. When it discovers new extensions just install the core Joomla extensions.

Comment: I, first uploaded the backup database. Fixed the database in Administrator page of Joomla and Updated Joomla Extensions and Core files of Joomla. Still same error, Amit.

Comment: Try to switch off the sef urls and rename htaccess file and check.

Comment: I tried putting off the SEF and renamed htassess.txt file, also tried changing the theme, I still get the same errors. I installed new Joomla and compared with the the ERRORED Joomla and rewrote the Joomla files from the new one to the old one, still I get the same error. Please help. I cant get off from this error in index.php page.

Comment: Can you send your link. I can check it and get an idea of whats happening. This error may be due to a missing component which is set as default home page.

Comment: The link is http://www.sasecrtn.bt/. Please have a look at it. Something might be missing, and I have no clue what that might be.

Comment: Your homepage is opening fine http://www.sasecrtn.bt/index.php?option=com_content&view=featured&Itemid=462&lang=en . Login to administrator go to main menu and select a component for default menu. That menu item should be default item.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I could't follow your instruction. Could you please explain a bit. I'm sorry, I'm quite a kind of a beginner in Joomla.

Comment: check this link how to make a menu tem default https://www.dart-creations.com/joomla/joomla-tips-and-tricks/5-changing-the-default-frontpage.html

Comment: Thanks Amit. It solved my issue. I was having such trouble solving it. And it was a simple solution.